# What do you do when your model doesn't learn? Weights never change

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to migrate this Tensorflow 1.1 code: [3.3 Omniglot Character set classification using Prototypical Network.ipynb](https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Meta-Learning-With-Python/blob/master/03.%20Prototypical%20Networks%20and%20its%20Variants/3.3%20Omniglot%20Character%20set%20classification%20using%20Prototypical%20Network.ipynb), to Tensorflow 2.x.

Here it is my code:

```
import os
import glob

from PIL import Image

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten
from typing import Tuple

def load_train_classes(root_dir: str) -> list:
    train_split_path = os.path.join(main_dir, 'splits', 'train.txt')

    # What the train.txt file contains are the character paths to be used in load images function
    with open(train_split_path, 'r') as train_split:
        classes = [line.rstrip() for line in train_split.readlines()]

    return classes

def load_images(root_dir: str, train_classes_names: list, dataset_shape: Tuple[int, int, int, int]):
    # Numpy array to store train images.
    dataset = np.zeros(dataset_shape, dtype=np.float32)

    # Load train images from disk.
    for label, name in enumerate(train_classes_names):
        alphabet, character, rotation = name.split('/')
        rotation = float(rotation[3:])
        img_dir = os.path.join(root_dir, 'data', alphabet, character)
        img_files = sorted(glob.glob(os.path.join(img_dir, '*.png')))

        for index, img_file in enumerate(img_files):
            values = 1. - np.array(Image.open(img_file).rotate(rotation).resize((img_width, img_height)), np.float32,
                                   copy=False)
            dataset[label, index] = values

    return dataset


# Create the function that get the embeddings. In this case, it is a CNN.
def get_embedding_function(img_shape):
    inputs = Input(img_shape)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1_1')(inputs)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool1')(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_1')(pool1)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool2')(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_1')(pool2)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool3')(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_1')(pool3)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool4')(conv4)

    # conv5 = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv5_1')(pool4)
    # pool5 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool5')(conv5)

    outputs = Flatten(data_format='channels_last')(pool4)
    print("Pool 4 shape: ", pool4.shape)
    print("Outputs shape: ", outputs.shape)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    #model.compile(tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=(1e-4) * 2), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model

def euclidean_distance(a, b):

    N, D = tf.shape(a)[0], tf.shape(a)[1]
    M = tf.shape(b)[0]
    a = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(a, axis=1), (1, M, 1))
    b = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(b, axis=0), (N, 1, 1))
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(a - b), axis=2)


main_dir = 'D:\\Temp\\MetaLearning\\data\\'
# number of classes
train_classes = load_train_classes(main_dir)
no_of_classes = len(train_classes)

# number of examples
num_examples = 20

# image width
img_width = 28

# image height
img_height = 28
channels = 1

# Now we define some of the important variables, we consider a 60-way 5-shot learning scenario
#number of classes
num_way = 60

#number of examples per class for support set
num_shot = 5

#number of query points
num_query = 5

#number of examples
num_examples = 20

h_dim = 64

z_dim = 64


num_epochs = 20
num_episodes = 100

# Load images from disk.
train_dataset = load_images(main_dir, train_classes, (no_of_classes, num_examples, img_height, img_width))

# Input image shape for embeddings function.
input_img_shape = (img_height, img_width, channels)
# Get the embeddings function
emb_function = get_embedding_function(input_img_shape)
# Get the optimizer as Stochastic Gradient Descend.
opt = tf.optimizers.SGD()

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # 2.1. Since we perform episodic training.
    for episode in range(num_episodes):
        # Select 60 classes RANDOMLY
        episodic_classes = np.random.permutation(no_of_classes)[:num_way]

        support = np.zeros([num_way, num_shot, img_height, img_width], dtype=np.float32)
        query = np.zeros([num_way, num_query, img_height, img_width], dtype=np.float32)

        # 2.2. Randomly sample n number of data points per each class from our dataset, D, and prepare our
        # support set, S.
        for index, class_ in enumerate(episodic_classes):
            selected = np.random.permutation(num_examples)[:num_shot + num_query]
            support[index] = train_dataset[class_, selected[:num_shot]]

            # 3. Similarly, we select n number of data points and prepare our query set, Q. (5 query points per class).
            query[index] = train_dataset[class_, selected[num_shot:]]

        # Add a new dimension at the end of the arrays to store the channels.
        support_set = np.expand_dims(support, axis=-1)
        query_set = np.expand_dims(query, axis=-1)

        # Create an array of arrays [[0, ..., 0], [1, ..., 1], ..., [num_way, ..., num_way]]
        # Each [0, ..., 0], [1, ..., 1], etc. has num_query elements.
        labels = np.tile(np.arange(num_way)[:, np.newaxis], (1, num_query)).astype(np.uint8)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # 4. We learn the embeddings of the data points in our support set using our embedding function.
            support_set_embeddings = \
                emb_function(tf.reshape(support_set, (num_way * num_shot, img_height, img_width, channels)))

            # Convert the label to one hot.
            # Convert labels, [[0, ..., 0], [1, ..., 1], ...], into [[1.0, 0., ..., 0.], [0., 1.0, ...], ...]
            y_one_hot = tf.one_hot(labels, depth=num_way)

            # 5. Once we have the embeddings for each data point, we compute the prototype of each class by taking the
            # mean.
            # embeddings of the data points under each class.
            class_prototype = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reshape(support_set_embeddings,
                                                        (num_way, num_shot, support_set_embeddings.shape[-1])), axis=1)

            # 6. Similarly, we learn the query set embeddings.
            query_set_embeddings = \
                emb_function(np.reshape(query_set, (num_way * num_query, img_height, img_width, channels)))

            # 7. We calculate the Euclidean distance, d, between query set embeddings and the class prototype.
            distance = euclidean_distance(class_prototype, query_set_embeddings)

            # 8. We predict the probability of the class of a query set by applying softmax over the distance d.
            predicted_probability = tf.reshape(tf.nn.softmax(-distance), (num_way, num_query, -1))

            # 9. We compute the loss as a negative log probability.
            loss = \
                -tf.reduce_mean(tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(y_one_hot, predicted_probability), axis=-1), [-1]))

            accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(tf.argmax(predicted_probability, axis=-1), labels), tf.float32))

            grad = tape.gradient([loss], emb_function.weights)
            opt.apply_gradients(zip(grad, emb_function.weights))

            if (episode + 1) % 10 == 0:
                print('Epoch {} : Episode {} : Loss: {}, Accuracy: {}'.format(epoch + 1, episode + 1, loss, accuracy))
```

If you want to try it, you have to download this [data](https://github.com/sudharsan13296/Hands-On-Meta-Learning-With-Python/tree/master/03.%20Prototypical%20Networks%20and%20its%20Variants/data).

When I run it, it seems that it doesn't learn anything:

```
Epoch 1 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.00333333108574152, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 1 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.00333333108574152, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 1 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.00333333108574152, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
```

To try to know what it is happening, I have added more convolutional layers:

```
def get_embedding_function(img_shape):
    inputs = Input(img_shape)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1_1')(inputs)
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1_2')(conv1)
    pool1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool1')(conv1)

    conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_1')(pool1)
    conv2 = Conv2D(96, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv2_2')(conv2)
    pool2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool2')(conv2)

    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_1')(pool2)
    conv3 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv3_2')(conv3)
    pool3 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool3')(conv3)

    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_1')(pool3)
    conv4 = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv4_2')(conv4)
    pool4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), data_format='channels_last', name='pool4')(conv4)

    outputs = Flatten(data_format='channels_last')(pool4)
    print("Pool 4 shape: ", pool4.shape)
    print("Outputs shape: ", outputs.shape)

    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)

    return model
```

But, it continues without learning:

```
Epoch 1 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 1 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 1 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 1 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 1 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 1 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 1 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 1 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 1 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 1 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 2 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 2 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 2 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 2 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 2 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 2 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 2 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 2 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 2 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 2 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 3 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 3 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 3 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 3 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 3 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 3 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 3 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 3 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 3 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 3 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 4 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 4 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 4 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 4 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 4 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 4 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 4 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 4 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 4 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 4 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 5 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 5 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 5 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 5 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 5 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 5 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 5 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 5 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 5 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 5 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 6 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 6 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 6 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 6 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 6 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 6 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 6 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 6 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 6 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 6 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 7 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 7 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 7 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 7 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 7 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 7 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 7 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 7 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 7 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 7 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 8 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 8 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 8 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 8 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 8 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 8 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 8 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 8 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 8 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 8 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 9 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 9 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 9 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 9 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 9 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 9 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 9 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 9 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 9 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 9 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 10 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 10 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 10 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 10 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 10 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 10 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 10 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 10 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 10 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 10 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 11 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 11 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 11 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 11 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 11 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 11 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 11 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 11 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 11 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 11 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 12 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 12 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 12 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 12 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 12 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 12 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 12 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 12 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 12 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 12 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 13 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 13 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 13 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 13 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 13 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 13 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 13 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 13 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 13 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 13 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 14 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 14 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 14 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 14 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 14 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 14 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 14 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 14 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 14 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 14 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 15 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 15 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 15 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 15 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 15 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 15 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 15 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 15 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 15 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 15 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 16 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 16 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 16 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 16 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 16 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 16 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 16 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 16 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 16 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 16 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 17 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 17 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 17 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 17 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 17 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 17 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 17 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 17 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 17 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 17 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 18 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 18 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 18 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 18 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 18 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 18 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 18 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 18 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 18 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 18 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 19 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 19 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 19 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 19 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 19 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 19 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 19 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 19 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 19 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 19 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 20 : Episode 10 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 20 : Episode 20 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 20 : Episode 30 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 20 : Episode 40 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 20 : Episode 50 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 20 : Episode 60 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 20 : Episode 70 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 20 : Episode 80 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 20 : Episode 90 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
Epoch 20 : Episode 100 : Loss: -0.0033333336468786, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107
```

What is it happening?

**UPDATE**:
I have used the following function to check if weights change, but it don't:

```
def assert_equals(weights_before, weights_after):

    result = True

    for a, b in zip(weights_before, weights_after):
        if (a.numpy() == b.numpy()).all():
            result = False
            break

    return result
```

Comment: I suggest you to take a deeper look into the loss, where is the log in there?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy If I add the log I get the same. I get the same values of Loss and accuracy for all the epochs and episodes: Loss: 5.703782558441162, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I have tried the original code, without any modifications, and it repeats the same value for loss and accuracy for all the epochs and episodes Loss: 5.703782081604004, Accuracy: 0.01666666753590107. Loss value is a little bit different from mine version.